# Android - Update ListView not Working

Tags: android, listview, refresh, adapter, items

I am trying to update a ListView at Android. I insert new items on the list and then call notifyDataSetChanged() and nothing happens! And I am using the runOnUIThread, that should work right?

Here is my code:

```
    @Override

//this is where I create the ListView with my custom adapter..

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Globals.getInstance().readWarehouse(this);
            Toast.makeText(this, "É:" + Globals.getInstance().getWarehouse().getJointNames().length , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            adapter = new CustomList(MainActivity.this, Globals.getInstance().getWarehouse());
            list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

Then I edit the content of this adaptar on another activity.. adding nore more item..
And I come back to this activity and then I call this method to refresh the list.. but nothing is happenning.. Here is the code where I refresh:

```
@Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ((BaseAdapter) list.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        Toast.makeText(this, "onResume triggered.. and list not refreshing.. even after the call made before to notify.." , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

Can someone help me? Thanks alot!

Comment: you are killing me with that runOnUiThread inside the onResume() method

Comment: can you post the code of the second activity where you modify the list?

Comment: the list size is being updated because I check it with a Toast message...

Comment: can you please post the code of the adapter CustomList. there should be sth going on with the adapter i believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by creating the layout myself dynamically adding new rows and stuff like that.. using the Layout Inflater.

It's not the best solution, but know I have full control on the layout :)

Thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score -1):

Check if adapter (CustomList) `getView` function is called after `onResume`.
If `getView` function is called, check if data is updated in `Globals.getInstance().getWarehouse()`.

Comment: the getView function is not being called after onResume, what should now? the getView function is just being called on the start of the activity, but when I launch another activity and get back to the first.. the getView is not called, I am sure because I used a Toast message... thanks in advance